# 所有, 所都, 全都 variation in the same sentence

Tags: grammar, vocabulary

Do these three sentences mean the same?

I guessed all wrong.  Or Everything I guessed was wrong.

我所有猜错了。

我所都猜错了。

我全都猜错了。

Edited:  Any other choices besides 所有, 所都, 全都?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. 我所有猜错了。try: 我猜错了所有的。
2. 我所都猜错了。try：我把所有的都猜错了。
3. 我全都猜错了。：Good!

Answer (score 1):

我所有猜错了。 You can say 我所有的都猜錯了 我全都猜錯了 我全猜錯了

我所都猜错了。所都 doesn't make any sense. It's an incorrect phrase.

我全都猜错了。 Correct.